# AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'query_param'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Views.py -

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def view_items(request):
    if request.query_params:
        items = Item.objects.filter(**request.query_param.dict())   #error line
    else:
        items=Item.objects.all()
    serializer=ItemSerializer(items,many=True)
    if items:
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `**request.query_param` should be changed into  `**request.query_params`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to filter by name.

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def view_items(request):
    name = request.query_params.get("name", None)
    if name:
        items = Item.objects.filter(name=name)
```

I would suggest you to use django-filters, that's a better way to structure your code.

Create Item app

urls.py

```
app_name = "app-name"

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register("items", ItemViewSet, basename="item")
```

views.py

```
class ItemViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    filterset_class = ItemFilterSet
```

serializers.py

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ("id", "name", "label")
```

filters.py

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class ItemFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ("name", "label")
```

Comment: More an advise than an answer to the question